# Airy style differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for a substitution that would convert:

$$y''+(ax-b^2)y=0$$

To the more familiar format (Airy DV):

$$y''(u)+k^2uy(u)=0$$

Would *something like* $k^2u=ax-b^2$ do that trick?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What does (u) mean? As a function of u or multiplied by? Priming derivatives risk becoming ambiguous whenever changes of variable occur. I would recommend to rewrite specifying exactly which partial derivatives you take.

Comment: Rather, try $$u = \frac{ax-b^2}{(ak)^{2/3}}$$